# "Left join" of two different Java objects

Tags: java, left-join

I have a list of Object1 (`List<Object1>`) and a list of Object2 (`List<Object2>`)

- Object 1 has multiple properties, including `id`
- Object 2 has multiple properites, including `object1id`

I have some SQL background and what I'm trying to do is to perform a "left join" on

`object1.id = object2.object1id`

This would result in a `List<Object3>` that represents the left join.
I could hardcode an algorithm in Java (for... for...), but I'm sure this wouldn't be efficient with at least a complexity of n*m.

Do you have a better solution? (with code if possible, thanks!)

Comment: So you want a collection that only has objects from the first list and second list if they're equal based on their ID?

Comment: based on the left join, the new collection would have all elements of collection1, and only the matching elements of collection2 based on matching ID

Comment: Is any of your list ordered ?

Comment: I believe I could have only `List<Objects2>` ordered right away

Comment: O(n*m) is only bad if `n` and `m` are large, or the operation is done frequently. Get it working, then see if it is non-performant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to do something that Java is not really meant for.

If you are able to do it, you would be better off **adding an attribute to `Object1`**, which would be a list of `Object2` containing the objects related to `this`.

If you can't, we still have the option of doing it naively, else you could try something like that:

```
HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet<Integer>(list2.size());
for(Object2 o : list2) {
    hs.add(o.object1id);
}
//hs contains all the ids of list2
List<Object1> result = new ArrayList<Object1>(); //Or another class implementing List
for(Object1 o : list1) {
    if(hs.contains(o.id))
        result.add(o);
}
```

Not pretty since you have to store all the ids in an HashSet, but since adding and accessing elements in HashSet are O(1) (theoretically), the algorithm is O(n+m)

If your `Object3` class is constructed with an `Object1` and `Object2`, use an `HasMap` instead of `HashSet` where the keys are ids, and the values object2. The last `for` loop in the code will become:

```
Object2 o2 = hs.get(o.id);
if(o2 != null)
    result.add(new Object3(o, o2);
```

---

Further to Óscar López comment:

If your objectid1 your not unique, you have to adapt the code as follows:

```
HashMap<Integer, List<Object2>> hm = new HashMap<Integer, List<Object2>>();
for(Object2 o : list2) {
    List<Object2> l = hm.get(o.objectid1);
    if(l != null) {
        l.add(o);
    } else {
        List<Object2> l = new ArrayList<Object2>();
        l.add(o);
        hm.put(o.objectid1, l);
}
//hm is map, where each entry contains the list of Object2 associated with objectid1
List<Object1> result = new ArrayList<Object1>();
for(Object1 o : list1) {
    List<Object2> l = hm.get(o.id);
    //l contains all Object2 with object1id = o.id
    for(Object2 o2 : l)
        result.add(new Object3(o, o2));
}
```

Still in O(n+m), but with bigger constants...

Comment: This won't work if more than one object in `list2` has the same `object1id`.

Comment: I don't understand your comment that Java is not meant for this.

Comment: You can do it, but Java was not design for this kind of purposes. It's like doing functional programming in Java: nothing forbids it, but it really not the best and more efficient way to code. Join rows in tables works really good with SQL because SQL language was thought to do that kind of computation. Whereas Java is not: instead of applying SQL methods and structure to Java, you should try to adapt your problem and your way of thinking to the language your are using.

Comment: Actually, you suggest logic for inner join, but in question left join was mentioned. Instead of `Object2 o2 = hs.get(o.id); if(o2 != null) result.add(new Object3(o, o2);` should be `Object2 o2 = hs.get(o.id);result.add(new Object3(o, o2);`

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Java 8, you can leverage [streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html). It might look something like this (assuming `id` is the id of the Object1 to look up):

```
List<Object3> newList = obj2List.stream().filter(x -> x.object1id == id).map(x -> obj2To3(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The case provided is pretty vague, so it's hard to give a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

Create an index on List. Scan List and fill the index:

```
HashMap<Integer, Object2> index=HashMap<Integer, Object2>();
for (Object2 obj2: list2) {
   index.put(obj2.object1id, obj2);
}
```

Then, scan the List and do the join:

```
for (Object1 obj1: list1) {
   Object2 obj2=index.get(obj1.id); // may be null
   Object3 obj3=new Object3(obj1, obj2);
}
```

Comment: This won't work if more than one object in `list2` has the same `object1id`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe an `O(n*m)` solution is inevitable, *unless* a more complex data structure infrastructure is created - efficient joins in a database are [implemented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Implementation) using indexes, hashes, etc. Also bear in mind that a correct implementation should consider the case where more than one object in `list2` has the same `object1id` - my code works in this case, but all the solutions that simply add `obj2.object1id` to a `Set` or as keys in a `Map`, will fail.

But is the implementation complexity worth it? if the input lists are small an `O(n*m)` solution will work just fine. Here's my proposal, using good old nested loops:

```
List<Object3> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object1 obj1 : list1) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (Object2 obj2 : list2) {
        if (obj1.id.equals(obj2.object1id)) {
            list3.add(new Object3(obj1, obj2));
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
        list3.add(new Object3(obj1, null));
}
```

For the above to work, I'm using an output object that looks like this:

```
public class Object3 {
    private Object1 obj1;
    private Object2 obj2;
    public Object3(Object1 obj1, Object2 obj2) {
        this.obj1 = obj1;
        this.obj2 = obj2;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works and it was what I was thinking about. But I was wondering if few optimizations could be done, with sorting or something like that. I can't believe a left join in SQL has a complexity of O(n*m)...

Comment: @user3019499 as I said above: doing an efficient join is not such a trivial task, take a look at some possible [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Implementation). Is the implementation complexity worth it? if the lists are not too big, the above answer will perform just fine.

Comment: @user3019499 also, my answer is (so far) the only that works if there's more than one object in `list2` that has the same `object1id`, a very likely scenario in a real-life database.

Comment: @user3019499 It will be O(n*m) if you're trying to produce the entire set of `n` rows, and you have to perform a linear search of `m` to find all the matches. Preventing this is why database indexes (or Java's hash) were created. Also, the OP must decide what IS fast enough. Not everything needs to be optimally fast.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution might be converting the List of Object2 to a Map. Then iterate through the Object1 List and get the Object2 from Map, ultimately creating the Join and adding result in Object3 List.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that they implement some common interface (this will make things easier, notably with casting), then this is relatively straightforward.

It's still O(nm), since you do have to go through both lengths of the list to find elements to add.

```
public interface JoinInterface {
    int getId();
    int getObject1Id(); // likely baggage here
}


public static List<? extends JoinableEntity> leftJoin(List<? extends JoinableEntity> left,
                                               List<? extends JoinableEntity> right) {
    List<JoinableEntity> result = new ArrayList<>();

    result.addAll(left);
    for(JoinableEntity aLeft : left) {
        for(JoinableEntity aRight : right) {
            if(aLeft.getId() == aRight.getObject1Id()) {
                result.add(aRight);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```