# How to join two datasets using java in a way like left outer join in SQL

Tags: java, spring-boot, data-structures, aws-lambda, stream

I am new to java world. I have two data sets with me. I need to make a single data set with all the details joined together, as in SQL left outer join.

First Data Set ( Java List )

[image: First Data Set ( Java List )]

Second Data Set (Java List)

[image: Second Data Set (Java List)]

The Output I am expecting ( Java List )

[image: The Output I am expecting ( Java List )]

Can you guide me how to achieve this using lists, streams or any other data structure in java. I am planning to implement this in a AWS Lambda function which has to be written using java.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593733/left-join-of-two-different-java-objects

Answer (score 0):

This has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57865058/left-join-using-java-stream-on-two-lists). Basically, you should be using map operation to achieve this using Java Stream API